# knockoutjs datatable via json not refreshing

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js, datatable

I'm new to jQuery, Bootstrap & KnockoutJS so I'm looking for a little help.

I followed this example: http://abrudtkuhl.github.io/Simple-Knockout-Js-Paging-Datatables/ and it works well but I can't get the data to refresh.

My implementation has some criteria fields and a search button so the only thing different is that the data call is triggered by an onclick event:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#search").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("invoiceStudents.cshtml?yr=" + $("#year").val() + "&dt=" + $("#diet").val(), function (data) {

            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
            $("#results").DataTable({ responsive: true });
        });
    });

    function ViewModel(data) {
        var self = this;

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    };
});
```

When I change my criteria and click search I can see that different JSON data is being returned from the server but the table has the data from the first search I do, no refresh happens.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `applyBindings` every time you get data, in fact you shouldn't.

call `applyBindings` once (on page load), then simply just update your data, the binding will then see to your UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the search is clicked you are instantiating a new ViewModel and applying it to your view.  Try instead instantiating it once, and updating it on click.

Ideally, you would not set click handlers here.  You should instead put data-bind="click: mySearchMethod" and define a method on your ViewModel to handle this, and your ViewModel would update accordingly.

Similarly, you should not reference eg #year in your search method, it should use the observable properties of your ViewModel.

The goal here is that your ViewModel knows as little as possible about your view, which allows you to freely change your view without affecting your logic.

Here's how I would do it:

```
$( function() {
    var viewModel = new ViewModel,
        view = $( '#results' );
    ko.applyBindings( new ViewModel, view.get( 0 ) );
    view.DataTable( { responsive: true } );
} );

function ViewModel() {
    var now = new Date;
    this.year = ko.observable( now.getFullYear() );
    this.dt = ko.observable();
    this.foo = ko.observable();
    this.bar = ko.observable();
}

ViewModel.prototype.search = function() {
     var viewModel = this;
     $.getJSON("invoiceStudents.cshtml?yr=" + this.year() + "&dt=" + this.dt(), function (data) {
          viewModel.foo( data.foo );
          viewModel.bar( data.bar );
     } );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. After reading your answers plus a little digging around I fixed the problem:

```
    var studentData = [];
    var historyData = [];
    var viewModel = {
        students: ko.observableArray(studentData),
        history: ko.observableArray(historyData)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I wasn't looking for overly elegant, just something working for now. I made a simple view model (I didn't realise that you only have one per page plus one ko.applyBindings). data.result is because my JSON is wrapped in a result tag.

```
  $("#search").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("json/invEducationStudentSearch.cshtml?yr=" + $("#year").val() + "&dt=" + $("#diet").val(), function (data) {
            viewModel.students(data.result);
        });
    });
```

My html was as simple as:

```
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: students">
          <tr>
              <td><span data-bind="text: id"></span></td>
              <td><span data-bind="text: fn"></span></td>
              <td><span data-bind="text: ln"></span></td>
              <td><span data-bind="text: loc"></span></td>
              <td><span data-bind="text: coy"></span></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
```